# Passing two or more variables in external layout which has been included in current activity

Tags: android, data-binding

Suppose I have an external layout which I am using in current activity. I am using databinding in the current activity. Suppose I have two variables in the current activity and I need both of them in the external layout that I have included. How can I pass both of them to the external layout. I know that one can be passed like below code:

```
<include
      layout="@layout/layout_external"
      bind:student="@{student}" />
```

But how two variables can be passed?

Comment: I have got the solution. No need to answer now.

Answer (score -1):

@Edit after comment Mihai Chelaru

Try to use BindingAdapter

Try to build:

```
@BindingAdapter({“bind:student”, “bind:lesson”})
    public static void printData(){
        Log.d(TAG, student.toString());        
        Log.d(TAG, lesson.toString()); 
    }
```

and in your XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    app:name=”@{stduent.name}”
    app:lessonName=”@{lesson.title}” />
```

I based on: 
https://medium.com/@vlonjatgashi/bindingadapter-with-multiple-attributes-in-android-data-binding-3e872caf1ef8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23774766)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru ok thanks :)  I will fix it and try to comment better :)